# How can we uninstall multiple instances of SQL Server 2008 without restarting the O/S?

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can we uninstall multiple instances of SQL Server 2008 without restarting the O/S?

SQL Server installer is failing with error:

> Server needs to restart after one instance uninstalled.

It is not practical for us to restart the server after each uninstall to uninstall every single instance.

Comment: Well, if the **installer** tells you so - you'll have to do it. I don't know of any way to "trick" the installer into uninstalling multiple instances of SQL Server 2008 - once he starts asking for a restart, there's usually no way around a restart.

Comment: It does that so it can stop and remove the services. I'm pretty sure if you stop the services (all of the impacted services) beforehand you can do this neatly. In addition, there are ways to force SS to bypass that check, but it requires twiddling bits in Windows, and there's lots of corner cases to miss something.